# os x kernel call function on all processors

Tags: macos, concurrency, driver, cpu, iokit

I am implementing my first driver on OS X (10.8.4). My driver should read MSR (0x198) on each processor every second and print the values to system.log.

I am using IOWorkLoop and IOTimerEventSource to wake up every second and call a function that prints MSR value, but I can't find any guide/documentation about how do I call the function on all processors.

What mechanism would you recommend to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
void mp_rendezvous_no_intrs(void (*action_func)(void *), void *arg)
```

This will run function **action_func** with argument **arg** on all cores.

You can find the source code of this function here:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/osfmk/i386/mp.c